# Elastic - prevent updating documents

Tags: elasticsearch, versioning

Can I make documents immutable? As in not have them be rewritten when a document is submitted to the same id?

```
POST "localhost:9200/index001/_doc/1" // First time it is created
'
{
  "stuff": {
      
  }
}
'

POST "localhost:9200/index001/_doc/1"  // Fails
'
{
  "otherstuff": {
      
  }
}
'
```

Could elastic's _version field help with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `index API` with a specific `id`, elasticsearch will update that document with the newer document. But if you use create `API`with specific `id`, you allow elasticsearch for "put-if-absent" behavior. it means, by using `create`, the document index operation will fail if a document by that `id` already exists in the `index`.
This is how you can use `create` in elasticsearch lower 7:

```
POST index001/_doc/1?op_type=create
'
{
  "stuff": {
      
  }
}
'
```

and this is using for elasticsearch 7:

```
POST index001/_create/1
'
{
  "stuff": {
      
  }
}
'
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, elasticsearch documents are immutable as they are stored in segments which are immutable, and any update to an existing document means(creating a new document and marking old documents as deleted). **But this doesn't make them immutable externally.**

You can simply use the `GET` API based on document id before sending the update request or if you want to avoid the extra API call, use an [optimistic locking doc of ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/optimistic-concurrency-control.html) and implement accordingly to avoid further update to your documents.

Comment: this is somewhat misleading - almost all big data dbs/stores have underlying immutable storage layout, but that doesnt make them immutable externally.

Comment: @shay__ thanks for your feedback, edited answer to avoid any confusion.